# form.is_valid() is always returning false without showing any errors

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms

I am pretty new to python and Django and I am using the built-in user system of Django to create a registration from.
Here's my view 
`

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #print 'success'
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
        #print 'fail'

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
    #print args
    return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

`
and here's the register.html template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h2>Register</h2>
    <form action="/accounts/register/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.errors }}

      {{ form.non_field_errors }}

      {{form}}

    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**No matter what, form.is_valid() is always returning false without giving out any errors.** I have been trying it since forever.

EDIT: I changed the view to the below one, it is working now, but I am not getting the exact reason, also there are no indentation errors in both the views.

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')

    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    args['form'] = form

    return render_to_response('register.html', args)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance :D and also Happy new year :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't show any errors because you always re-instantiate a new, unbound, form. Don't do that; the pattern in the docs is perfectly clear and you should follow it.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
else:
    form = UserCreationForm()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

args['form'] = form
return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

Comment: Even without the else condition, it is working for my second view. +Daniel Roseman

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your second view *has* the else condition.

Comment: Sorry and yeah, it's working I forgot to restart the server when I changed it before, anyways why does it matter because one it gets into the if condition it will be redirected, otherwise it goes into the else condition. +Daniel Roseman

Comment: It works because it does not re-instantiate the form if it fails validation. There are *two* if statements, and the else is on the outer one.

Comment: yep, My bad. . Thanks anyways and Happy new year :D.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any else condition in your views;
you have tor write `args['form'] = UserCreationForm()` starting of the function; ex;

```
def register_user(request):
   args = {}
   args['form'] = UserCreationForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()

           return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/register_success')
   args.update(csrf(request))
   return render_to_response('register.html',args)
```

Comment: Once it enters into the if condition it redirects, so I think using args at the beginning or the end doesn't matter.

Comment: It will redirect,only if form is valid otherwise it will just display the form without errors.